# VBA Excel how to solve a spontaneous error message

Tags: excel, vba

Running a VBA Excel macro gives sometimes an error. Not always and every time it happens on a different moment when combining Word documents. Sometimes after 10 document and another time after 50 documents.
The error message is "Deze opdracht is niet beschikbaar" (This command is not available) without further information.
Is this a problem that somebody has seen before? Does somebody know would could be the cause of this?
The Macro looks as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim HandleidingNaam As String
Dim HandleidingMap As String
Dim ModuleNaam() As String
Dim Mededeling As String
Dim Titel As String
Dim StandaardNaam As String
Dim PadnaamNaarHandleidingen As String
Dim AantalGebruikteTekstModules As Integer
Dim AantalTekstModules As Integer
Dim RegelCounter As Integer
Dim ModuleCounter As Integer
Dim TekstModule As Word.Document
Dim Template As String
Dim Taal As String
Dim Temp As String
Dim blnStart As Boolean
Dim ModuleRange As Range
Dim WordDocDialog As FileDialog



PadnaamNaarHandleidingen = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Worksheets("Hoofdstukken indeling").Select
AantalTekstModules = Range("AantalModules")
AantalGebruikteTekstModules = Range("AantalGebruikteModules")
Taal = Range("TaalKeuze")

'Vul een array met alle benodigde module namen
ReDim ModuleNaam(AantalGebruikteTekstModules)
ModuleCounter = 1
For RegelCounter = 1 To AantalTekstModules
    Temp = Range("FileNaam").Offset(RegelCounter, 0)
    If Temp = "-" Then
        GoTo NextModule
    End If
    ModuleNaam(ModuleCounter) = Range("FileNaam").Offset(RegelCounter, 0)
    ModuleCounter = ModuleCounter + 1
NextModule:
Next

'Bepaal adres van handleiding template afhankelijk van taal
Template = PadnaamNaarHandleidingen & "\" & Taal & "\Templates\" & "Masterhandleiding " & Taal & ".dotx"

'Open Word template
On Error Resume Next
'Kijk of Word al draait
Set WordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
If WordApp Is Nothing Then
    ' Start Word
    Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Het is niet gelukt Word te starten!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    blnStart = True
End If
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize

'Open document
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Template)
WordApp.Selection.EndKey

'Voeg alle module uit array samen
ModuleCounter = 1
For RegelCounter = 1 To AantalTekstModules
    Set TekstModule = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=PadnaamNaarHandleidingen & "\" & Taal & "\Tekstmodules\" & ModuleNaam(ModuleCounter))
    TekstModule.Content.Copy
    WordDoc.Activate
    WordApp.Selection.EndKey wdStory
    WordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph ' paste at the new paragraph
    WordApp.Selection.Paste
    TekstModule.Close ' close doc after paste
    ModuleCounter = ModuleCounter + 1
Next

'Sluit en bewaar het document
Mededeling = "Geeft een documentnaam en locatie in."
Titel = "Invoervenster handleidingnaam"
StandaardNaam = "VGEMxxx-ttxxx - Installation and User Manual VGE Pro xxx"

HandleidingMap = "Handleiding"
HandleidingNaam = "VGEM-Temp"
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 PadnaamNaarHandleidingen & "\" & Taal & "\" & HandleidingMap & "\" &    HandleidingNaam & ".docx"

ExitHandler:
On Error Resume Next
If blnStart Then
'Als we Word hadden gestart, sluiten we het nu weer
    WordApp.Quit savechanges:=False
End If
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Some times it runs without problems.
Restarting my computer doesn't have any effect.

I hope that someone has seen this before and suggests a solution.

Comment: The first  step towards debugging it is get rid of the "On Error Resume Next" and then you might at least stand a chance  of knowing where it goes wrong and in what context.

Comment: Googling, assuming it's "Run-time error '4605': This command is not available"  "This problem may occur if you do not have a document open, or if the document that you are referencing is not open. Word can only change the properties of an open (or visible) document."  [You receive run-time error 4248, 4605 or 5941 when you try to change properties on an unopened document in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813983)